# Getting total using Union All

Tags: mysql, sql

So here is my situation. I have 1 query that gets results grouped by date then I union all a second query that gets the totals (no grouping by date). My issue is I am calculating the average of fields and when I want to total up the average my numbers don't add up.

Here is my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa3a91/10)

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    t.end,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (t.start != t.end) THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t.start, t.end) ELSE 1 END) / COUNT(t.id) as averageTime
FROM store t
GROUP BY t.end
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Total',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (t.start != t.end) THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t.start, t.end) ELSE 1 END) as averageTime
FROM store t
```

Right now the second query just gives the total not the total of the average. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

To clarify since there is some confusion...

I need to get the average per grouped date by how many items were in that group

timeDiff / count(t.id)

Since I am not grouping in the union all query it is doing it as a whole then dividing. I hope that makes more sense.

The first query is correct the data output is as follows:

1, 1.6667, 3 (Those are the averageTime values from the first query)
5.6667 (Should be the total row) Right now I have it out putting 10 that is the total before the first rows were averaged out.

Comment: Why don't you use avg function then sum them up?

Comment: I'm confused, do you want the `SUM` of the averages (use `AVG` in the first query), of the average over all days at the end? The first is quickly sorted with a `WITH ROLLUP` of course, avoiding the need for a `UNION`.

Comment: timeDiff / count(id) -> GROUPED BY DATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe first part of the query can probably be written as:

```
SELECT t.end,
       AVG(CASE WHEN t.start != t.end THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t.start, t.end) ELSE 1
           END) as averageTime
FROM store t
GROUP BY t.end;
```

Presumably, you want the averages of the averages -- rather than the overall average.  I assume this because your query is calculating the overall average.

One way is the brute force way:

```
SELECT t.end,
       AVG(CASE WHEN t.start != t.end THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t.start, t.end) ELSE 1
           END) as averageTime
FROM store t
GROUP BY t.end
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', avg(AverageTime)
FROM (SELECT t.end,
             SUM(CASE WHEN t.start != t.end THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t.start, t.end) ELSE 1
                 END) as averageTime
      FROM store t
      GROUP BY t.end
     ) t;
```

Comment: No the output for the total row is 1.8889 it needs to be the sum of the first 3 rows, 5.6667.

Comment: I just switched avg to sum in the last query and that is the results I needed. Thanks for the right direction ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But, I suppose you need Average. As @samD mentioned,

the second part of you query can be written as

SELECT
    'Total',
    AVG(CASE WHEN (t.start != t.end) THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t.start, t.end) ELSE 1 END) as averageTime
FROM store t

Answer (score 0):

You're mistakenly assuming that the `COUNT(t.id)` in the first query represents the total number of rows, whilst it is actually also affected by the `GROUP BY` clause. If you multiply the separate rows by their number of days the totals also add up. Remove the division by `COUNT(t.id)` and the totals will add up, and you will correctly have the grouped SUMs as expected.

I'm just not sure how that solves your problem since you're not really clear on that: you simply cannot add all averages together and expect them to add up to a global average, that's not how math works: the sum of averages of arbitrary sized subgroups is rarely equal to the straight unweighted average of all groups together.

Comment: No that is I am not averaging from rows I am averaging by items in the date. So each row is its own average based on how many results were in that date range. The total is just supposed to be the sum of those averages. Not the overall average.